# Help needed in replicating FX Implied Vol Surface

Tags: implied-volatility, fx, stochastic-volatility, volatility-smile, volatility-surface

I am relatively new to this area and am doing some self studying on SLV model. I am however getting stuck on trying to replicate this implied vol surface (which I will use to calculate the local vol) [image]

The strikes and implied vols are calculated using the equations on slide 7 [here.](http://faculty.baruch.cuny.edu/lwu/9797/emsflec6impliedvol.pdf) For the most part, I am getting close but my strikes appear to be wrong. [image] I feel like the issue is coming from how am I calculating the forward rates: $f = S_0 e^{\tau(r_d- r_f)}$. I am not entirely sure where I am going wrong and hoping someone can shed some light on how I can replicate this. I think it may be in how I am calculating $\tau$ (I am just taking the maturity column in units of years). Any help would go a long way, thanks!

Comment: The range 2.5 - 5.5 should be your strike? If so, that's wrong. Would you mind posting your exact formula (say for 1 year to make thinsg simple) bc it makes it easier to see what you did.

Comment: Absolutely. $K_{ATM} = f e^{1/2 \sigma^2 \tau}$ & $K_{put,call} = f \text{exp}(1/2\sigma^2 \tau \pm N^{-1}( \Delta_{p,c} e^{r_f \tau}  ) \sigma \sqrt{\tau} )$ where the $\pm$ is for a put and call respectively. Here, $\tau = 1$ year, $\sigma$ is the implied vol, $r_f = 0.6352$ and $f = 1.257 e^{1 \times (1.1607-0.6352) }$. I will mention that in this figure, the paper mentions that yields are quoted annually and need to be converted to local forward rate. I am not to sure what that means with respect to how I calculated $f$.

Comment: Your values need to be in % throughout. 1.1607 is 0.11607 and so forth.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That was a typo on my comment. Within my code which produced the figure in the original post, they were properly written in percentage.

Comment: How did you convert the delta to strike? Plerhaps this could be an issue as there are several delta conventions..

Answer (score 0):

You still did not post your exact formula, which means it's impossible to determine what is wrong. Therefore, I'll post a working example.

[image]

I used Julia and manually defined the ppf. This is equivalent to python's norm.ppf() or excel's NORMSINV().

Afterwards, I simply copied your formula. This gives a strike of $\approx$ 1.256 which should be correct. Since you get values around 3.5, there is something wrong in your code.

As a side remark, for Vols quoted with premium included in the delta quote, one must use a root finder (e.g. Brent) and solve numerically as explained for example by [Wystup and Reiswich, 2009](http://hdl.handle.net/10419/40186).